# JavaFX textflow hide overrun text (clip or ellipsis)

Tags: java, javafx

In my application, I use a `TextFlow` that contains up to three `Text`-children. When the text is overrun, the text seperates into multiple lines (that is what I have understood to be called "text-wrapping", which I do not want, I guess?). I need the Text-Flow to clip the overrun text. For `Labeled` there is the [`-fx-text-overrun`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) style attribute - the values clip or ellipsis would be fine for me, but this is not available for `Text-Flow`s. I tried setting the pref-Width of the TextFlow to `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`, as that is suggested [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) but that did not help and rather seems to force the TextFlow to wrap the text to multiple lines. 
What should I do?

I am using a TextFlow (instead of a Label for example) because the Text objects inside the TextFlow need to be styled differently (the text in the middle needs to be bold). Is there maybe a better alternatvie for the TextFlow that allows me to clip overrun text?

Here is an example:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextFlow example = new TextFlow();
        example.getChildren().addAll(new Text("A very long text."), new Text("So long that will wrap, if it's parent is too small."), new Text("But instead the overrun text should be clipped."));
        example.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        example.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 14px");

        HBox wrapper = new HBox(example);
        wrapper.setMaxWidth(30);
        wrapper.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");

        HBox root = new HBox(wrapper);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does placing the TextFlow in an HBox help?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @VGR Sadly it doesn't. Actually the TextFlow is inside a HBox. Might that be part of the problem?

Comment: Instead of an HBox, I tried a FlowPane, and I called `setPrefWrapLength(Double.MAX_VALUE)` on it.  That seems to get closer to your goal.

Comment: @VGR Maybe I did something differently than you, but when I do what you suggested, the overrun text is not wrapped anymore, but also not clipped.

Answer (score 0):

A FlowPane with its wrap width set to Double.MAX_VALUE seems to prevent wrapping.

To clip the text, you can create a Rectangle, bind its width and height to the FlowPane’s width and height, and pass it to the FlowPane’s setClip method.

```
FlowPane wrapper = new FlowPane(example);
wrapper.setPrefWrapLength(Double.MAX_VALUE);

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.widthProperty().bind(wrapper.widthProperty());
rect.heightProperty().bind(wrapper.heightProperty());
wrapper.setClip(rect);
```